# Animated equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to animate an equation in Beamer with the `\alt` command. Unfortunately, there is some "movement" between the two equations. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<-2>{Example}
\[\alt<1>{\max}{\min}(1,2)=\alt<1>{2}{1}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then, my `\max` and `\min` commands have not the exact same length. Therefore, the sign `=` for instance (but also the `(1,2)`) moves between slides 1 and 2.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `\minx`, a `\min` that is right-aligned in a box of the width of `\max`.
2. `\minxx`, a `\min` that is `\llap`ed at the end of a `\hphantom{\max}`.

With the `mathtools` package one can replace `\llap` with `\mathllap` and `\makebox` with `\mathmakebox`.

Addition care is needed if `\max`/`\min` is preceeded by any content as `\hphantom` and `\widthof` would hide this content from `\max` and `\min`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\minx}{%
    \mathmakebox[\widthof{$\max$}][r]{\min}%
}
\newcommand*{\maxx}{%
    {\max}%
}
\newcommand*{\minxx}{%
    \hphantom{\max}\mathllap{\min}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<-2>{Example}
\[
\alt<1>{{\max}}{\minx}(1,2) = \alt<1>{2}{1}
\]
\[
\alt<1>{{\max}}{\minxx}(1,2) = \alt<1>{2}{1}
\]
\[
\alt<1>{\maxx}{\minxx}(1,2) = \alt<1>{2}{1}
\]
\[
\max(1,2) = 2
\]
\[
\minx(1,2) = 1
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newlength{\widthofamin}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<-2>{Example}

\settowidth{\widthofamin}{$\min$}

\[\hspace{-\widthofamin}\alt<1>{\phantom{\min}\max}{\phantom{\max}\min}(1,2)=\alt<1>{2}{1}\]

% Even inline, there's no extra space : $\hspace{-\widthofamin}\alt<1>{\phantom{\min}\max}{\phantom{\max}\min}(1,2)=\alt<1>{2}{1}$\\
% if you compare with $\alt<1>{\phantom{\min}\max}{\phantom{\max}\min}(1,2)=\alt<1>{2}{1}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This method adds a virtual `\max` in front of the `\min`, and vice-versa, to ensure that both are right-aligned to the equal. But the side-effect is that it adds white space in front of the equation, which we fix with that `\hspace`.

[image: Extra space?]

I'm sure there is a less dirty solution using `\savebox` and friends, but I'm not familiar enough with these commands to build you an example.

Comment: This is an already quite convincing solution. Of course, it is kind of dirty, but at least it gives a better result than before!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to write a macro using @Qrrbrbirlbel's answer below. I had to use the `\mathmakebox` version to specify a length and throw in the vphantom to prevent the slide from jumping vertically. I hope someone finds it useful!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\maxwidthof}[2]{\maxof{\widthof{#1}}{\widthof{#2}}}
\newcommand<>*{\robustalt}[2]{
  \alt#3
    {\makebox[\maxwidthof{#1}{#2}]{#1}}
    {\makebox[\maxwidthof{#1}{#2}]{#2}}
}
\newcommand*{\maxwidthofm}[2]{\maxof{\widthof{$#1$}}{\widthof{$#2$}}}
\newcommand<>*{\robustaltm}[2]{
  \alt#3
  {\mathmakebox[\maxwidthofm{#1}{#2}]{#1}\vphantom{#1#2}}
    {\mathmakebox[\maxwidthofm{#1}{#2}]{#2}\vphantom{#1#2}}
}

\begin{frame}%
  \[
    \robustaltm<1>{\max}{\min}(1,2) = \robustaltm<1>{2}{1}.
  \]
  x $\robustaltm<1>{\alpha}{\underbrace{\alpha}_{\rm apples}}$ \uncover<1-3>{done.}\\
  x \robustalt<1>{apples}{oranges} \uncover<1-2>{done.}
\end{frame}%

\end{document}
```