# Arguments of tikzset inside a beamer document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I am trying to use `tikzset` with an argument in a `beamer` document, and I am having an error I do not understand.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My try} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{boite/.style={draw=#1}}
    \node[boite=red] {The text} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

The error I get with this code is

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.10     \end{tikzpicture}
```

Note that the exact same code in an `article` works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{boite/.style={draw=#1}}
    \node[boite=red] {The text} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the same issue given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118781/finding-the-depth-of-nesting-in-a-macro-call You can take out the setting to your preamble or put `[fragile]` option to the frame

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Percusse's comment solves this issue, and I just adapt from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118781/finding-the-depth-of-nesting-in-a-macro-call). 
There are (at least) three solutions.

Either the `frame` can be given the option `[fragile]`, or replace `#1` by  `####1` (see the the linked [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118781/finding-the-depth-of-nesting-in-a-macro-call) for details on why four `#`s are needed), or simply put the `tikzset` in the preamble.

A working solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{My try} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{boite/.style={draw=####1}}
    \node[boite=red] {The text} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```