# Label illegal parameter

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\title{Newton's Approximation of $\pi$}

\author{Daniel Rui}



\begin{document}



\begin{frame}

\titlepage

\end{frame}



% \section{Part 1}



% \begin{frame}

% \frametitle{Outline}

% \tableofcontents

% \end{frame}



\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Approximation}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.6\textwidth}
Newton begins with a circle centered at $\frac 12$, as shown. He draws a vertical line at $\frac 14$, and uses two different methods to find the area of the shaded region.
\column{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
circ/.style={circle, draw, solid, fill=white, inner sep=0.75pt,
             label=#1,
             node contents={}
             },
every label/.append style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize}
                    ]
% shaded area
\fill[gray!30]  (0,0) arc (180:120:1.5cm) |- cycle;
% axis
\draw[->]   (-0.5,0) -- + (4.0,0) node[below left] {$x$};
\draw[->]   (0,-0.5) -- + (0,3.0) node[below left] {$y$};
% rest of image
\draw (0,0) node[circ=above left:$B$] arc (180:0:1.5) node[circ={}];
%
\draw[densely dashed]   (60:1.5) -- (0:1.5) node[circ=below:$\frac{1}{2}$];
\draw                   (60:1.5) node[circ=$A$] -- (0:0.75) node[circ=below:$D$];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Using my compiler (it’s an app called TeX), it gives me the following error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \test
```

[image]

On another compiler, it seems to work, but on this one, it is very consistently telling me that there is an error. Is this a compiler problem, or is there actually a problem in the

```
label=#1
```

that seems to cause a lot of trouble? I tinkered with that particular line a lot, and I believe it is the heart of the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the second frame, you need `\begin{frame}[fragile]` instead of `\begin{frame}`.

Comment: @marmot Can you explain the difference please? Why does LaTeX distinguish the two?

Comment: Did you see the posting [“Illegal parameter in \test” in Beamer + TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430506/5001)? (It's listed as a "related" posting to the right of your query.)